# What happens if you change the replication factor on existing hbase install

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I have a cluster with 12 nodes that currently have ~2.5 TB of data saved in  HBase tables.  The current replication factor is 3 and I don't actually need that level of integrity and would like to drop the factor to 2.

Aside from changing the replication factor in the `/etc/hbase/hbase-site.xml` file on each node is there anything else I need to do to migrate to a new replication factor?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the following:

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -setrep -R -w 2 /
```

This will change the replication of the existing files.  Changing the replication in the config would I presume change the replication of *new* files.